# How does this fit into the logic of "Functions are objects" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Just tried an experiment,

```
var f = function() { alert("yay, a function!"); };
console.log(f == function() { alert("yay, a function!"); });
```

, which printed `false` to the console. But, if Javascript `function`s are to be thought of as objects, then wouldn't that be no different than

```
var x = 5; 
console.log(x == 5);
```

???

Comment: `{} === {} // false`. `5` is not an object, it is a primitive.

Comment: all objects (including functions) are different from each other

Comment: Objects are compared based on their memory reference so if you created one funcion and then created another one, they will always have different instance memory references and they will always mark as false when compared.

Comment: You are confusing *referential equality* with *value equality*.  You created two indistinguishable functions.  They aren't the same function, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript, reference types can't be compared using equality operator(==).

so `consoloe.log([1,2]==[1,2])` will return false. 
and because function are instance of Object so it will also return false.

You can NOT use equality operator except for primitive types such as strings and numbers